# How to automaticaly add an incrementing numeric id for each td elements in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, auto-increment

I want javascript to automatically add an incrementing numeric id for each of my td elements.

I want a script at the bottom of each HTML page to tell what first id will be input for that page and ++ automaticaly for each next td element. I tried a lot of things with for loop and something is missing with my appendChild method, i just can't make it work but i know i'm almost there.

If someone could give a hand, it would be greatly appreciated!

Here is how a manually enter those IDs each new month :

```
<tr>
    <td id="603" class="offweekend"></td>
    <td id="604" class="offmonth"></td>
    <td id="605" class="offmonth"></td>
    <td id="606" class="offmonth"></td>
    <td id="607" class="offmonth"></td>
    <td id="608" class="offmonth"></td>
    <td id="609" class="weekend">1</td>
</tr>

<script>
       tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
        tdlength = tds.length;
        firsttd = 603;
        lasttd = firsttd + tdlength;
        for (i = firsttd; i < lasttd; i++){
            td.appendChild() //???That's where i'm confused, i'm i wrong 
                                  with this approach?
        }
</script>   

//Thank you, i'm still learning :)
```

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried please.

Comment: "to tell what first id will be input for that page": what does this mean? Are you hardcoding that value into the page and the JS uses that as reference for the rest of the numbering?

Comment: Ok i deleted it let me build it again...

Comment: Ok i edited my question. Andy, i'm not hardcoding it. I just want for each load that javascript write all my ids for that page. I want to save that time and also, i want to learn this for my future codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have a variable `firstValue` that stores what the id of the first td should be, you can use this:

```
document.querySelectorAll("td").forEach((v,i)=>v.id=i+firstValue);
```

- The `querySelectorAll` grabs all of the `td` elements in order as a NodeList.
- `v` is the td element and `i` is the position of the element in the array

Comment: I took your solution, it was exactly what i was needing. But i'll need to study  to understand that code line. Thank you very much! You really made my day :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `appendChild`. You can simply iterate through the cells and set the `id` immediately.

```
let id = 603;
const cells = document.querySelectorAll('td');
cells.forEach(function(el) {
  el.id = id++;
});
```

A small aside: I don't know your indended use but you might be better off using a data attribute for storing this information instead.

```
let id = 603;
const cells = document.querySelectorAll('td');
cells.forEach(function(el) {
  el.setAttribute('data-id', id++);
});
```

Comment: Thank you verymuch for helping me out. It was really appreciated!